# Can geoserver fetch tiles in EPSG:32633 from one server, convert and serve EPSG:4326 locally?

Tags: geoserver

The maps I would like to use served tiles using EPSG:32633
https://geodata.npolar.no/arcgis/rest/services/Basisdata/NP_Basiskart_Svalbard_WMTS_25833/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

- I need to access those maps as tiles from , for example http://localhost/svalbard/z/x/y  as  data with EPSG:4326

Can GeoServer do the job?  - if yes, please point me to a configuration example.

Comment: Yes, but it will look bad. Read the manual on cascading if you want to try anyway.

Comment: thanks - I failed to find a "manual on cascading" - but how bad? can I expect it to be?
I hoped that it fetched whole zoom levels and distorted it as required (only stretching/shrinking where needed for each zoom level?)

Comment: [geoserver cascading](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/cascaded/index.html) - it depends on what is on the tiles but each tile will be reprojected independently - labels will look most distorted